# Convert String (Json Array) to List

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to read Json  from a file, than convert to list.But i'm getting error at the beginnig of code, Json.load(). I couldn't figure out. 
Thanks.

```
import json

with open("1.txt") as contactFile:
    data=json.load(contactFile.read())
```

1.txt:

```
[{"no":"0500000","name":"iyte"},{"no":"06000000","name":"iyte2"}]
```

Error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 286, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: It is better to use `open("1.txt", 'r')`.

Comment: @user2931409: why is that? `'r'` is the default.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Oh I didn't know that. IMO because it is more human readable. If you say "it is verbose", I must agree with you. Any upvoter help!

Answer (score 6):

[`json.load()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.load) works on a file object, not a string. Use

```
with open("1.txt") as contactFile:
    data = json.load(contactFile)
```

If you do need to parse a JSON *string*, use [`json.loads()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.loads). So the following would also work (but is of course not the right way to do it in this case):

```
with open("1.txt") as contactFile:
    data = json.loads(contactFile.read())
```

Comment: Thank both of you ( @ thefourtheye and @ Tim Pietzcker ). I misunderstood json load and loads. It works now

Answer (score 4):

[`json.load`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.load) accepts a file like object as the first parameter. So, it should have been

```
data = json.load(contactFile)
# [{u'name':u'iyte', u'no': u'0500000'}, {u'name': u'iyte2', u'no': u'06000000'}]
```

Comment: Thank both of you ( @thefourtheye and @Tim Pietzcker ). I misunderstood json `load` and `loads`. It works now.